# No Mapping for GET /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Please find this project on GITHUB as [studentsbooks](https://github.com/radharamanaa/studentsbooks)

I am getting errror as below, even after following a proper tutorial. Kindly guide where i am going wrong. Feel free to clone the project. Committed Just now.

```
2021-04-23 20:45:38.227  INFO 16580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : 

Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-23 20:45:38.227  INFO 16580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-23 20:45:38.229  INFO 16580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2021-04-23 20:45:38.259  WARN 16580 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a class InsertInitialData class annotated as `@Component` and used `WebApplicationContext` with `autowired` annotation. Thymeleaf uses context to get initialized please find in below code.

```
@Component
public class InsertInitialData{

WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
public void setContext(WebApplicationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
@Bean //as it is from thymeleaf documentation, just passed the context! else is same!
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
    // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.context);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
    // SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and
    // enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms.
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    // Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can
    // speed up execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible
    // with specific cases when expressions in one template are reused
    // across different data types, so this flag is "false" by default
    // for safer backwards compatibility.
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Take a look at the repo, clone and run, using Spring boot run

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@EnableWebMvc` and override the below method in your `ApplicationConfig` class

```
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
```

Comment: tried to  run your project but facing error,
```
2021-04-23 17:50:11.628  INFO 28326 --- [extShutdownHook] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2021-04-23 17:50:11.634  INFO 28326 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-23 17:50:11.637  INFO 28326 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: We need to run in a certain way, "Spring boot run",

Comment: Ideally running the main class sufficient to replicate your case. Not required run using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

(It seems GitHub code does not match your  question.)

Try to remove [`ApplicationConfig.java`](https://github.com/radharamanaa/studentsbooks/blob/84cf6ab6af928a39d4da76b6133d2ebe1e7ea174/src/main/java/com/appl/studentsbooks/ApplicationConfig.java).

You set template resolver [explicitly](https://github.com/radharamanaa/studentsbooks/blob/84cf6ab6af928a39d4da76b6133d2ebe1e7ea174/src/main/java/com/appl/studentsbooks/ApplicationConfig.java#L35-L37), but it seems wrong.